# MySQLWorkbench text selection shows black text on a black background

Tags: mysql-workbench, selection, fedora

MySQLWorkbench 8.0.13 on Fedora 29 shows black text on a black background when I select text in the Query Editor.

[image: MySQLWorkbench query editor with text selection]

Any ideas for how to fix this? I've not noticed the problem with any other applications.

Comment: The colors for the SQL editors are defined in the code_editor.xml file. Did you change that by any chance?

Comment: I cannot find that file in ~/.mysql/workbench (And in any case, I do not remember editing it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in MySQLWorkbench. It has been fixed in the latest release:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/workbench/en/news-8-0-14.html

> The color used to highlight a query in the SQL editor was the same color used for the text, which made the selected query appear to be missing when it was highlighted. (Bug #28691256, Bug #92535, Bug #28715080)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colors in file: /usr/share/mysql-workbench/data/code_editor.xml

Comment: Should I need to change the default colours?